# Migrating from unencrypted Ubuntu 16.04 to LUKS Encrypted install of 16.04

Tags: linux, encryption, clone, ubuntu-16.04, luks

My company is working on implementing some Ubuntu Systems in a few of their new testing efforts and I have been tasked with an encryption solution for them. Having been a primarily Windows user with just a working knowledge of Ubuntu and Linux/Unix in general, this has been a bit challenging but intriguing. I know many in place encryption services work w/ Windows but have noticed a lack of these for Ubuntu and after reading 20+ posts on here about it, decided fresh install w/ full disk encryption is the only realistic option. That being said, some of the systems have already been in use, and would not be able to just be wiped and fresh installed w/ encryption. I would need ALL settings and changes as well as existing files copied over/backed up. Therefor, it's not as simple as copying over /home. I was curious what would be the best course of action for me, I have a full copy of the Partition (used gparted to make a quick copy to external) for my test machine and a fresh install of Ubuntu w/ LUKS. I am familiar with the basics of clonezilla, but I don't believe that will help me here from what I gather.

tldr: I need to move a full install of Ubuntu 16.04 to an encrypted disk. Some machines will be TPM enable and some will not have them, I need to know the best course of action for each. Thank you for helping a new Admin out.

BONUS if you can describe a way that doesn't require outside network access, but not required. I.e. if it needs a package, I can download it on a test PC to USB/CD/DVD and install the package offline.

Comment: Oh man, I swear I once typed a complete guide how to do this on some Stack Exchange site - probably this one. I can't find it and I don't have time to type it again right now, but you can try to search through my answers if you wish.

Comment: I appreciate it, I will definitely try to look through when I have the time. If you find it first, please feel free to post it here and I will happily mark it as an answer. Anything unclear about my question? As it's my first one, I tried to provide as much information as I thought was needed but I just want to be sure.

Comment: *That being said, some of the systems have already been in use, and would not be able to be wiped.*  If you have proper backups, they should. Otherwise, you have an occasion to both encrypt and test proper backup procedures :)

Comment: Apologies, they can be backed up, wiped, and then reinstalled with encryption once I find an error free way to do it without a chance of them losing data. That is definitely a clarification I need to make.

Comment: Similar non-Ubuntu specific question: [Encrypt an existing partition in Linux while preserving its data](https://superuser.com/q/216879/66039)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Described below is a procedure I have successfully used multiple times. It works for Ubuntu 16.04 and 18.04. Unlike the solution proposed by @Arno in their answer, it doesn't require manual editing of kernel boot options. Instead, it relies on `update-grub` generating proper config based on `/etc/crypttab` - a more canonical (pun unintended) solution which is also used by Ubuntu when installing with its default, LVM-based encryption. (this solution doesn't use LVM nor encrypted `/boot`)

> *I am not responsible for any data loss or other potential unpleasant consequences of following this guide. Make sure you have reliable backups before doing anything.*
>
> *I'm not testing this guide while I'm typing this. It's based on a (tested) [blog post by myself](https://gronostajo.tumblr.com/post/177797691569/install-ubuntu-1804-with-encryption-but-without) on somewhat similar case and some details I can remember.*

This guide assumes that:

- Ubuntu is already installed
- The system boots with (U)EFI, not BIOS/CSM
- `/boot` is on a separate partition<sup>1</sup>
- You can boot a live media of Ubuntu 16.04/18.04 or Pop!_OS 18.04 (from USB, PXE, DVD, whatever) <sup>2</sup>

If your `/boot` is not on a separate partition, extracting it is pretty straightforward: create a 200-500 MB partition anywhere, format it to ext4, copy current `/boot` content, add `/etc/fstab` entry, `update-grub`, reboot.

---

## 1. Backup

You have to back up current system partition(s). The easiest way to do this is to use Clonezilla. It's user-proof, no manual needed - just follow the instructions.

## 2. Shrinking partitions

LUKS headers take some of the space on a partition. Clonezilla/partclone can't restore images to devices smaller than source ones, so you wouldn't be able to restore image of unencrypted partition to encrypted container, because it's a tad smaller.

We then have to shrink partition(s) to be encrypted a little bit. Shrink them by 10 MB or more, just to be safe. The easiest way to do this is to use GParted. It's available on Ubuntu live media.

## 3. Making images of shrunk partitions

Either do this with Clonezilla again, or already familiarize yourself with *partclone*, which Clonezilla is using by default. We'll be manually restoring images with partclone later.

Cloning to an image with partclone:

```
sudo partclone.ext4 -c -s /dev/sda2 | pigz -0 > /mnt/backup/sda2.ext4.ptcl.gz
```

1. `partclone.ext4` is one of partclone's binaries dedicated to working with ext4. Each supported filesystem gets its own partclone binary.
2. `/dev/sda2` is obviously the partition you want to clone. I prefer to refer to partitions by their partlabel, eg. `/dev/disk/by-partlabel/os` - much cleaner IMO. `/dev/sda2` is more recognizable, though.
3. *pigz* is multicore gzip. `-0` tells it to favor speed over effective compression.
4. `/mnt/backup` here represents some external location where you want to store the image. If you've just used Clonezilla before, it can still be mounted under `/home/partimag`. If you want to mount an SMB share: `sudo mount -t cifs -o username=gronostaj //192.168.1.90/Backup /mnt/backup` (asks for password interactively)

## 4. Enlarge partition(s) to original size

We want to have that extra space for LUKS headers back, don't we? Resize partitions back to their original sizes.

## 5. Formatting to LUKS

**This is the moment where you loose your original data. Make sure your backups are okay.**

Format system partition(s) (except for `/boot`) to LUKS:

```
sudo cryptsetup luksFormat --type luks2 /dev/sda2
```

Open created container(s):

```
sudo cryptsetup open /dev/sda2 os
```

Make sure that entire encrypted container looks like random garbage and your old data isn't still readable:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/mapper/os bs=1M
```

(this will overwrite decrypted content of container with zeros, but encrypted content will look like random garbage)

## 6. Restoring images

Manually run partclone to restore images:

```
cat /mnt/backup/sda2.ext4.ptcl.gz | pigz -d | sudo partclone.ext4 -r -o /dev/mapper/os
```

If you took the easy path and made "shrunk" backups with Clonezilla, look in its output files, you'll easily figure out which are the partclone sources. Unless you set huge chunk size they will be fragmented, you have to `cat` them together before piping to pigz.

You should also adjust filesystem geometry to fit entire partition:

```
sudo resize2fs /dev/mapper/os
```

## 7. Enabling encryption support

First, chroot into the just-restored OS:

```
mkdir /mnt/os
sudo mount /dev/mapper/os /mnt/os
cd /mnt/os
mount --bind /etc/resolv.conf etc/resolv.conf
mount --bind /dev dev
mount -t tmpfs tmpfs tmp
mount -t sysfs sys sys
mount -t proc proc proc
sudo chroot .
mount -a
```

This terminal is now working on your installed instance of Ubuntu, not the live one.

Install *cryptsetup*:

```
apt update
apt install cryptsetup -y
```

It should create a file `/etc/crypttab`. If it didn't, don't worry, create it manually. Edit this file and add entries for partition(s):

```
os /dev/sda2 none luks
```

Save and quit editor. Rebuild initramfs:

```
update-initramfs -u -k all
```

Update GRUB entries:

```
update-grub
```

## 8. Removing extra password prompts

If you have more than one encrypted partition, then you have to type in the password for every single one on boot. LUKS however lets you add additional keyfiles that can be used to unlock partitions instead of password. You can store these keyfiles on encrypted `/` partition and use it to unlock subsequent ones.

Create a random keyfile:

```
dd if=/dev/urandom of=/luks.key bs=4096 count=1
```

Add it to non-root partition(s):

```
cryptsetup luksAddKey /dev/sda3 /luks.key
```

Add `crypttab` entries:

```
home /dev/sda3 /luks.key luks
```

Rebuild initramfs:

```
update-initramfs -u -k all
```

---

<sup>1</sup> Why I use separate `/boot`:

- It's easier this way ;)
- GRUB doesn't support LUKS2 yet, so `/boot` must not be on LUKS2 encrypted partition
- If you want to LUKS-encrypt `/boot` and LUKS2-encrypt `/`, then you have to enter password twice or [embed keyfile in initramfs](https://web.archive.org/web/20160101193137/http://missinglink.xyz/security/tutorial-debianubuntu-full-disk-encryption-luks-fde-including-encrypted-boot/improved-full-disk-encryption-add-luks-key-file-initrdinitramfs/) - too much of a hassle IMO, because...
- Encrypted `/boot` alone doesn't make you any less vulnerable, because even if your `/boot` is encrypted, your EFI System Partition cannot be, so attacker can tamper with it and eg. use their custom malicious kernel/initramfs instead of your one from `/boot`. (to fix this, you have to [build a self-container GRUB binary and sign it with your private key](https://github.com/JohnstonJ/ubuntu-secure-boot), then use UEFI Secure Boot to verify it)

Define your own threat model and decide what level of security (and against what) you need.

<sup>2</sup> You can try your luck with other Ubuntu versions or rescue CDs such as [GRML](https://grml.org/), but your mileage may vary. I've experienced this procedure failing just because live media didn't match the system.

Comment: This looks like an extremely complete answer, which is really appreciated as someone just learning more than the basics, I appreciate it. I will be testing this out and hopefully marking this as accepted within the next few days if all goes well. By chance, would this all be capable without internet access?

Comment: Hm, good question. Partition and filesystem tools are included on regular Ubuntu live media and you don't have to install them to disk. cryptsetup is available live too, but you'd have to add Ubuntu media as an apt source to install it to disk. Definitely possible, installer does this. Clonezilla and partclone may be problematic, but you can use dd instead - it will work, but it's very inefficient (it's making byte-for-byte copy of disk, including unused space).  pigz won't be available, but you can replace it with gzip, which will be slower because it uses only one core.

Comment: Second question, I used clonezilla to make a copy of the orginal data on my test machine, and reinstalled with encryption upon installation with the live disk after reading everywhere that this was the "easier way". But you are saying to do it all with the edited installation and restoring the backup after encrypting or a fresh installation and added the old files? I must have made a disconnect somewhere in there, sorry.

Comment: I have a clonezilla live disk that I used for the image originally and a 16.04 live disk as well. Just some of the systems don't have internet access where they are located in the building and it would be much easier for me if I didn't have to relocate them to do it and move them back.

Comment: With this method you basically move the original system into the encrypted container and add bits that are required to boot. Fresh install with encryption from the very beginning is easier, but if your backup restoration procedure is very time-consuming, this method may be better. (but then you have to validate your backup strategy)

Comment: Awesome, definitely will try your way then. Are any of the mentioned packages able to be downloaded from the source and installed from say a USB media device? That would make it offline friendly as well without having to skip any steps or change them. Though I am not 100% on how to install packages for use from tar files despite my best efforts, learning would be simple if I knew it was a fix.

Comment: You can download .deb files for respective packages and install them manually offline with dpkg. This won't be fun, though ;) Or you can juggle both disks. Clonezilla disk will do just fine for pigz & partclone. Just make sure to make the subsequent steps with Ubuntu and figure out how to install cryptsetup from Ubuntu media.

Answer (score 1):

You could image the root partition, format it with LUKS, mount it and overwrite it with the image. Then a few changes to GRUB would be needed so it would decrypt it at boot. *I haven't tested the steps below*, they are just a lead.

I assumed that `/boot` is on `sdb1`, the root partition is on `sdb2` and `/media/hdd` is an external drive. We are on a Live USB in an admin prompt.

#### Encrypt the root partition

```
dd if=/dev/sdb2 of=/media/hdd/diskimg bs=1M
cryptsetup luksFormat /dev/sdb2
cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sdb2 enc_root
dd if=/media/hdd/diskimg of=/dev/mapper/enc_root
```

#### Mount the partitions

```
mount /dev/sdb2 /mnt
mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt/boot
```

#### Configure GRUB

Note the partition's UUID by running:

```
blkid /dev/sdb2
```

Edit `/mnt/etc/default/grub`, find the line that says `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"`. Change it to the following, replacing `device-UUID` by the UUID you noted in the previous step.

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash cryptdevice=UUID=device-UUID:enc_root root=/dev/mapper/enc_root"
```

Then update the GRUB config:

```
mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev
mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys
mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc
chroot /mnt
update-grub
exit
```

And unmount everything:

```
umount /mnt/dev
umount /mnt/sys
umount /mnt/proc
umount /mnt/boot
umount /mnt
```

And reboot. A few pitfalls:

- I haven't tested any of this and haven't played with Linux partitions for a while, so I'm almost sure I forgot or messed up something. Wait for people to proofread and fix it.
- This assumes that `/boot` is on a separate partition, it wouldn't work if everything was on the same partition.
- On a UEFI system, don't forget to also mount the EFI partition where it belongs.
- `dd` will copy *everything* including free space, a quicker method would be to copy only the files in the partition.

Good luck!

Comment: This looks like a great answer, like you said I will wait til someone proofreads since I don't personally have the Linux know how yet to make sure all of this is error free etc. Do you think I should include the way the partitions are organized? Will that help with the process? 

Currently I am doing:
sr0 1024M rom
sda
-sda1 /boot
-sda2 1k
-sda5_crypt
--ubuntu--vg-root LVM
--ubuntu--vg-swap LVM

Sorry, I am not familiar with how to format these comments yet.

Comment: You should run `lsblk` and add the result to your question as code (there is a button for that in the editor). That would tell us exactly how your partitions are organized.