# Encrypting the hard drive without formatting

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, encryption, ubuntu-18.04, luks

Is there a way to encrypt an hard drive in ubuntu after installation? I know we can encrypt while installing the OS but I dont want to re-install the OS. There are 300gb of files and applications including databases in my system. The thing is I dont want to lose my data, so suggest me a way to encrypt without formatting. Moving files between partitions is not an option.

Way to encrypt full hdd without formatting?
Or atleast
Way to encrypt the root partition without formatting?

OS: Ubuntu
Version: 18.04

Comment: Could you tell us which OS it is?

Comment: lsb_release -a    will tell you which version of Ubuntu you are running.  Run it in a terminal and update your post with the version of Ubuntu.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Migrating from unencrypted Ubuntu 16.04 to LUKS Encrypted install of 16.04](https://superuser.com/questions/1417262/migrating-from-unencrypted-ubuntu-16-04-to-luks-encrypted-install-of-16-04)